# I try rendering a video in render but the whole render goes black

Tags: rendering, video

I'm Testing the BGCV VHS Look on Blender based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okr6dBK6QqU).

I used a MP4 video as a base and I've followed the instructions correctly, however when I render the video the whole video is black.

The audio is still there but the video is missing, I'm b beginner in Blender so I don't really know how to fix this.

Comment: What happens when you do a simple render (F12)?

Comment: I tried doing a Simple Render, The Render is also Black.